# How to import text into postman

Tags: postman

I am new to postman and am given what I believe is a postman export. I can manually add these fields into postman but is there a quicker way to import into postman? I tried to import in postman via raw text, but unrecognized format.

```
POST /WebService/WebService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Host: dev.helloworld.com
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.28.4
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: f62e3cd8-91c0-4238-844c-592aeb19e0a3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 596
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<sDatabaseName>Apples</sDatabaseName>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look like a Postman export.
That looks like a (raw) console log output.

A Postman export would be in JSON format.
The information you have would need to be input manually as you have described.

However, once it has been input, you could then export the collection you create (in JSON format) and you would have a copy that you can then re-import whenever you need to.

Alternatively, if you have the cURL command you could import that as raw text.